# How can I avoid having to manually type "sudo modprobe ndiswrapper" to initiate my usb wifi

Tags: wireless, boot, usb, scripts, modprobe

I have installed ndiswrapper and the driver bcmwlhigh5.inf for my netgear usb wifi. After booting my wifi is always offline. I can activate it using the command

sudo modprobe ndiswrapper

the wireless connection activates and stays active. Unfortunately this system is for my spouse who is blind. I don't want her to have to type terminal commands. Is there a file that I can append the aforementioned command to that will start the wireless on boot?

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Answer (score 1):

You can set up a cron job for this that is run at every reboot. Modify the root crontab by typing `sudo crontab -e` and add the line

```
@reboot <whatever you want to do>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I learned this from a question of mine which was answered by Oli. 
You should add it to the end of `/etc/modules`. Here's a command that will handle that for you. 
Run it on Terminal and restart the system.

```
echo ndiswrapper | sudo tee -a /etc/modules
```

I think thereafter it will start automatically. I did it for my system and it's working perfectly fine.